# no matching function for call to std::list::remove_if( function()::predicate )

Tags: c++, predicate, stdlist, argument-dependent-lookup

So, defining a predicate inside a function and use as `std::list::remove_if` argument is not allowed?

---

Consider the following code, which fails to compile:

```
struct a { };

int main()
{
    struct pred { bool operator()( const a& ) { return false; }  };

    std::list< a > l; // fill l
    l.remove_if( pred() );

    return 0;
}

error: no matching function for call to 
    ‘std::list<a, std::allocator<a> >::remove_if(main()::pred)’
```

---

Now, if I replace `l.remove_if( pred() );` with

```
pred()( *l.begin() );
// or
pred p;
p( *l.begin() );
```

which `remove_if` does internally, it compiles and works as expected.

And even more: if I move `struct pred` to be defined *outside* main, both tests work as expected.

---

This doesn't make *any* sense to me.

I thought that it could be something with dependent names and ADL and things like this, but... the argument of `remove_if` is an **instance, not a type**. It's true, that this is a template function and the argument's type is still resolved, but..

Can somebody explain what and why happens?

Comment: Make sure you're using C++11. In C++98, you couldn't use local classes as template arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your very first question is that yes, prior to C++11 some types (such as local types) are NOT allowed as template parameters. See 14.3.1/2:

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type
>   compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a
>   template argument for a template type parameter.

Since `remove_if` is a template, you cannot use the local predicate as its parameter.

Comment: I see. To me, this is more like a restriction, rather than a missing feature and I don't understand why it's in the old standard. Doesn't make sense to me. This is interesting.